# Quickbook IPP Can't Delete

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, devkit

I'm getting the error "cannot DELETE synchronized TXN_HDR record. Use REVERT object API" when I try to delete an invoice using Quickbook IPP for QB Desktop. My request and response are below. I removed the authorization header for security. Any ideas?

Request:

```
POST https://services.intuit.com/sb/invoice/v2/[realmId] HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 404

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
                  <Del RequestId="b31649561ac1dbc0cadcca5b3d6c8ef9" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
                     <Object xsi:type="Invoice"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <Id idDomain="NG">1002</Id>
                     </Object>
                  </Del>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2013 15:43:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Response-Routing-Time: 200
Content-Length: 392
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" ?><RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><Error RequestId="0a7cb165f7274ed39a7311e4c3c66e51"><RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName><ProcessedTime>2013-09-09T15:43:02.993Z</ProcessedTime><ErrorCode>-3002</ErrorCode><ErrorDesc>cannot DELETE synchronized TXN_HDR record. Use REVERT object API</ErrorDesc><DBErrorCode>20924</DBErrorCode></Error></RestResponse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremy,
Invoice delete is not supported in v2. You can revert the last change to an invoice via the API but cannot delete it. You can only delete it from QuickBooks.

regards
Jarred

Comment: Is this a feature that is available in V3? If so, is intuit still accepting applications for the private beta?

Comment: Yes it is. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/invoice